# Refer another component methods in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs

it is very common for us to `require` a second component controller to access its methods from first component in Angular JS. The framwork does it for us when we use `require` in our component. My question here is do we have something similar in React, or how can we achieve the same thing in React ? Sample code snippet that I am talking about is below.

```
angular.module('demoModule', [])
.component('demoComponent1', {
  require: {
    anotherComponent: '^anotherCompoent'
  },
  controller: function() {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      this.anotherComponent.someMethod(this);
      console.log(this);
    };
  },
  templateUrl: 'sample.html'
});
```

Suggestions are appreciated with thanks.

Comment: This is kind of an anti-pattern in react. You should avoid calling imperative handles on components. In React you try to achieve that by using composition of components and hooks. It's hard to tell from this abstract example how to do it in react. Can you provide a concrete example of your use case? It might just be an XY Problem here.

Comment: Different framework, different interaction between components. There is no real question here, so what do you hope to achieve from the question

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) attribute for what you wish to achieve here.

When you assign a component a ref, its current attribute will be your custom component:

```
 class Parent extends React.Class {
    constructor(props) {
        this._anotherComponent = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this._anotherComponent.current.someMethod()); // This is where the method gets called
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AnotherComponent ref={this._anotherComponent} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Note**: This will only work if the child component is declared as a class, as per documentation found here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component

You can utilize `componentDidMount()` that's similar to that of the magic method `$onInit` in angularJS.

Comment: There is just that tiny question that says, does it makes sense to do it in a similar way like a different framework does it, or would it be better to review to adapt to the framework

Comment: While this may work it is strongly discouraged to do it that way if it can be done in a declarative way (which is in the vast majority of potential use cases).